# How to echo immediately (php) without using flush or ob_flush?

Tags: php, echo, flush

I have a php script that needs to be installed on different servers (and will be used by different users). In my script I have something like this (after clicking on the submit button):

```
  echo "preparing... please wait";
    ...
    ...
    echo "step 1 done";
    ...
    ...
    echo "step 2 done";
```

different server has different ways to compile PHP. Some are running PHP as fastcgi/suphp (support custom `php.ini`) some are running PHP as CLI (doesn't support php.ini) and as we all know that flush and `ob_flush` doesn't always work (if gzip is enabled or server's setting: `output_buffering` is on, or `zlib.output_compression` is on)

Also I was told that sometimes browser will have gzip compression on.

So by using flush and `ob_flush`, it may not always work.

So my question is, can I still achieve the same goal without using flush or `ob_flush`?

Comment: in my experience i was never able to get the behavior your expecting. I recall with perl it was possible.

Comment: There is no reliable and guaranteed way to get what you ask for. You are using the wrong means for your purpose. Instead implement some progress tracking client side code (ajax) and check the progress on a periodical or event-driven base. You also get a _much_ more beautiful output that way...

Comment: @arkascha can you please provide some sample code?

Comment: Sorry no. What I suggest is no secret, you will find lots of examples for this on google. Have fun!